# I want to write a loop for Selenium changing the parameters of the website. I am having trouble writing calling the website in the loop

Tags: python, selenium

```
for zipcode in zipcodes:
    for page  in pages:
        site = 'https://www.website.com/home?search=+zipcode&cursor=+page'
```

where i want it to be

```
site = 'https://www.website.com/home?search='+zipcode'&cursor='+page
```

however it does not really work in seleinum

Comment: Why doesn't your example work?  Telling us "it doesn't work" doesn't say much.  What does it do?  Do you get an error?

Comment: Assuming `zipcode` and `page` are strings, your example would work, if you add a plus sign between `zipcode` and `'&cursor`.

Comment: there is a syntax error when i try to use  the site = 'https://www.website.com/home?search='+zipcode'&cursor='+page

Comment: As I said, you're missing a plus sign after `zipcode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
for zipcode in zipcodes:
    for page  in pages:
        site = 'https://www.website.com/home?search={}&cursor={}'.format(zipcode,page)
```